# Predefine Windows filename in any save dialog?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a technology to predefine Windows filename in any save dialog? I want to add a prefix to my files with the current date? Is there a technology that I can replace the file name with a prefix in any save dialog?

Comment: The date is already in the file's metadata, to have it in the file name as well is useless.

Comment: Yes, it's a bad habit.

Comment: @TomWijsman: What if you have a Programm when you can't change the name? It's always the same name so it's get overwritten when you save it? Is this still useless application?

Comment: That's a totally other question then.

Comment: @TomWijsman: What do you mean? Can you elaborate? You can edit my question to make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conceivably write an AutoIt script that runs in the background and sets a global hotkey. Then every time you are in a save dialog, you could press the hotkey and have the script get the handle of the dialog and auto-insert the current date in the filename field.

If you want to automate it even further, I guess you could have the script poll for save dialogs at regular intervals (say every 5s, although I don't know about the possible impact on the system), then have it add the date as required whenever such a dialog is found open.

That's one way you could possibly accomplish this. As for the script itself, someone far more well-versed in AutoIt coding needs to help, else you can always post on the [AutoIt forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/).

Comment: Is there something similar for Linux? Sounds like a macro to me?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is not something that is exposed

I know that due to time constraints the "defaultsavename" attribute in microsoft silverlight language is not open to editing though it is on the list of things to do for the developers however if the attribute exists, its probably set on a program by program basis by the coders

Comment: So it can't be done? Is it to complicated to write a kernel module?